# Can I use Code Connection on a Bedrock Dedicated Server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I know how to apply mods to a Minecraft World with Code Connection, but how can I do this with a Bedrock Dedicated Server?

Comment: Does the same method not work? What happens, does the `/connect` command give an error?

Comment: @Penguin No, it just doesn't do anything

Comment: @Penguin Maybe I should try a different port...?